# Live ECG plot in WPF

Tags: wpf, graph

What would be the best (easy and fast) approach to plot live ECG data in a WPF application? I am thinking about writing my own control that would use paths to visualize the signal. But maybe there are ready to use graph libraries that suite my need?
Do you have any experience in that area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, however all third party components using retained graphics mode were too slow. I've decided to use WritableBitmap with double buffering and unsafe code and an Image control.

Comment: Can you please share your solution? I have to do the same thing, and after long tryouts with Dynamic Data Display I've came to the same conclusion..it's just too slow.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/). Its very flexible and performance beats all of the commercial products I have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however live plot performance was really below expectations

Answer (score 2):

LightningChart is fast enough. It works in WPF according to docs. I've only used it in WinForms though.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Visifire](http://visifire.com/silverlight_line_stepline_charts_gallery.php) has live updating and a line graph-- I'm not sure if it's fast enough for your needs, though.  But it is free until you sell something and opensource.

Answer (score -1):

[LightningChart](http://arction.com/products) supports WinForms and WPF to visualize your data fast and easily.
[ECG plot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbFjB.png)

(I'm a software developer at Arction Ltd, LightningChart development company).